# Zend Form Element Checkbox returns 0 both when checked and unchecked

Tags: php, zend-framework

My code is as follows:

Zend Form:

```
$explicit = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('explicit');  
    $explicit->setLabel('Explicit?');  
    $explicit->setAttribs(array('id'=>'explicit'));  
    $explicit->setCheckedValue(1);  
    $explicit->setUncheckedValue(0);
```

Zend View:

```
<?php echo $this->{$this->element->explicit->helper}($this->element->explicit->getName(), $this->element->explicit->getValue(), $this->element->explicit->getAttribs());?>
```

Zend Controller:

Checked with:

```
$explicit = $this->getRequest()->getPost('explicit');
```

and with:

```
$formSongs->explicit->isChecked()
```

$checked returns 0 everytime and isChecked is always false... Am i ommitting something from the view helper? or its a different problem?

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Zend Form you can do this:-

```
 $explicit = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('explicit ','explicit',
                                                array('checkedValue'  => 1,
                             'uncheckedValue' => 0,)
                        );
      $explicit  ->     setLabel('Explicit?'); 
                 ->     setValue(1);  //set default value to one.
```

Comment: tried it @Mubo but no success... And why you have to use javascript to check a value? Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox should provide that?

Comment: I have edited it,  this works for me to. and populates the value 1 in the table Data.

Comment: Yes @Mubo if i setValue(1) at first it works... but the second time i submit the form it doesnt... It works only 1st time... it should work all the time or am i wrong?

Comment: That should work normally that way if you are not doing some thing else in somewhere. test it with checked and unchecked too.

Comment: Do you use populate() function?

Comment: You can use populate to put the value that you want.